# Setting stylesheet of QMainWindow covers QWidget

Tags: python, pyqt5

I have made my own progress bar in PyQt5, which is a QWdiget:

```
class ProgressBar(QWidget):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(ProgressBar, self).__init__(parent)

        self.percentage = 0
        
        #self.setGeometry(200, 200, 120, 120)

        self.label = Label(str(round(self.percentage * 100 / 360, 2)) + " %")

        self.layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.label)

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        rectangle = QRect()
        rectangle.setX(10)
        rectangle.setY(10)
        rectangle.setWidth(100)
        rectangle.setHeight(100)

        gradient = QConicalGradient()
        gradient.setColorAt(0, QColor(5, 44, 50))
        gradient.setColorAt(1, QColor(178, 255, 246))
        gradient.setCenter(rectangle.center())
        gradient.setAngle(180 + self.width)

        pen = QPen()
        pen.setBrush(QBrush(gradient))
        pen.setWidth(self.width)
        pen.setCapStyle(Qt.RoundCap)

        painter = QPainter(self)
        painter.setRenderHint(QPainter.Antialiasing)
        painter.setPen(pen)

        painter.drawArc(rectangle, 180 * 16, self.angle*16)
...
```

When I add it in QMainWindow, some parts of it are covered by the color I set to QMainWindow using self.styleSheet. If I comment this line, the background is white and the widget is no longer covered. How could I change this behavior and set a background color without this being covered?
This is how I add it:

```
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.setMinimumSize(660, 400)

        self.progress_bar = ProgressBar(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.progress_bar) 
        self.setWindowFlag(Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
        self.setFocusPolicy(Qt.StrongFocus)

        self.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(80, 90, 10)")
```

Comment: How do you add the progress bar to the main window? What is the stylesheet you're using? Please provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: updated the code, sorry for misunderstandings

Comment: When posting examples ensure that they are *actually* reproducible. Your code has an unknown or mistyped class name (`Label`), `self.width` should be accessed with `self.width()` ([`width()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#width-prop) is a QWidget standard property, and you should not overwrite it), `self.angle` is never declared.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two main problems in your code:

1. you're setting a *global* background in the stylesheet, which means that **all** widgets will have that background;
2. you're adding a child widget (the label) to the progress bar, and for the above reason that label will have the background set in the stylesheet; since you've also added the label to the progress bar of the layout, the label will cover the whole space available, resulting in painting *over* the progress bar (painting always happen from the bottom to the top, and child widgets are always above their parents);

So, the solution is to set the stylesheet in the correct way. If you want to set the background only for the main window, specify the class in the selector:

```
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        # ...
        self.setStyleSheet("QMainWindow {background-color: rgb(80, 90, 10);}")
```

Generally speaking, "anonymous" stylesheets should be avoided, especially if set on parent widgets or even in the top level window. Read more about this on the [stylesheet syntax](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-syntax.html) documentation.

Comment: You can use `#` in the stylesheet to select objects by name, e.g. `#MainWindow` or `#centralWidget`.

Comment: @JasonC I know, but since it's unlikely that a QMainWindow would have another QMainWindow as a child, then there's no need to specify an object name as selector (which would require Qt to traverse the whole child tree for *any* QWidget). It would make more sense to specify the type selector, then: `MainWindow` (without `#`). Also, setting the stylesheet for the main window or the central widget is *not* the same thing: the former will apply the style for the *whole* window area (including menubar, toolbars, statusbar and dock widgets), while the latter will only style the central widget.

Comment: It was a general tip; not aimed at you personally. For the QMainWindow case it can be useful if you're setting the stylesheet on the QApplication rather than on specific QMainWindows (and the application has more than one QMainWindow). `#MainWindow` and `#centralWidget` were examples of selecting objects by name, I didn't mean they were the same effect.

Comment: @JasonC Yes, well, the OP did set the QSS on the window, so I followed their approach. For any other case, the link in the post (and, now, these comments :-) ) is quite explanatory. Also, following your first comment, and considering the standard Qt Designer naming convention, it should be `#centralwidget` (with the lowercase "w"). About your last comment, it depends: creating a selector rule for the main window is generally sufficient for the background property of the *whole window* (menubar, statusbar, etc), including the central widget, but the style might always override it.